# Xcode encountered an internal logic error

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Need help
I get the following error when i try to change anything in buildsetting section in Xcode 4.Once i change the value immediately i get the error as follows and xcode crashes.

> Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to  continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt  Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result  in the loss of all unsaved data.**

The log says as follows

```
Process:         Xcode [13518]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.0.2 (99)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-990000~53
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [103]

Date/Time:       2011-07-10 18:14:39.963 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10D573)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          6925 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  913 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      860BC8C7-2425-44F4-87CA-B9680C691297

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4A2002a
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSCFSet removeObject:]: attempt to remove nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff85188d06 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff83e300f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff85188b47 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff85188ad4 +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8272342b -[NSCFSet removeObject:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x000000010002ee1b -[DVTModelObjectGraph didDeleteModelObject:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x0000000100516b97 -[IDEFileReference _invalidateStartingWith:changeBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x00000001005167f5 -[IDEFileReference _invalidateResolvedFilePath] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8273965b __NSThreadPerformPerform (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff85125f21 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff85124119 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 11  0x00007fff851238df CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff83234ada RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 13  0x00007fff8323483d ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 14  0x00007fff83234798 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 15  0x00007fff800a4a2a _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 16  0x00007fff800a4379 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff8006a05b -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff80062d7c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 19  0x0000000100000eec

abort() called
objc[13518]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff824a3886 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82543eae abort + 83
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000100949290 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 343
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000100949de3 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 563
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8006a15b -[NSApplication run] + 651
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80062d7c NSApplicationMain + 364
6   com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000100000eec 0x100000000 + 3820

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8249a996 select$DARWIN_EXTSN$NOCANCEL + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff824704a7 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 388
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82470094 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246fbbe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f4e8 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8245575a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82455dcd mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85124452 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff851238df CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000114016598 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 314
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82721ead __NSThread__main__ + 1429
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e8b6 _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e769 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82499286 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85145ef2 __CFSocketManager + 818
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e8b6 _pthread_start + 331
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e769 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82490316 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82494131 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001151d9f04 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 330
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82721ead __NSThread__main__ + 1429
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e8b6 _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e769 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82490316 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82494131 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff824048ba CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 804
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8240455b startIOThread(void*) + 139
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e8b6 _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e769 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f30a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f71c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f30a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f71c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f30a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f71c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82455796 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff824919b5 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 211
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff824917e9 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 134
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001005ffd82 -[IDEIndexableMainThreadProxy indexableFiles] + 132
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000100555ca3 -[IDEIndex _purgeStaleData] + 471
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001005553c3 __36-[IDEIndex _finishIndexingWorkspace]_block_invoke_0 + 198
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8274b081 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 681
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8274ad37 ____startOperations_block_invoke_2 + 99
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82491610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246fbb1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 239
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f4e8 _pthread_wqthread + 353
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f30a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f71c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8246f385 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8245575a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82455dcd mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85124452 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff851238df CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff854939dc SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 380
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e8b6 _pthread_start + 331
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8248e769 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff5fbffa08  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbff9a8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00000000000034ce  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff9c0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff9a8
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x000000011c9c44e0  r10: 0x00007fff8249f8ca  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x00007fff70509258  r13: 0x00000002062d89c0  r14: 0x0000000201f95260  r15: 0x00000001001505e0
  rip: 0x00007fff824a3886  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x0000000005ba9000
```

Comment: If you do not format this, then I doubt anyone will bother tryingbto read it.

Answer (score 3):

"Xcode crashes." ...and stop.

This is a bug with Xcode, and it's nothing you're doing wrong in particular (so we can't tell you how to do it right). We also don't have the source for Xcode, so we can't debug the problem.

Please file bug reports with the respective software vendors for crashing bugs with your favorite IDE or developer utility. They're really the only ones who can fix the crashing bug. For Apple stuff, use http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when I had some wrong values/type in the info.plist.
In particular I had a Icon file key pointing to an Array type which is wrong (should be a String type). If you have made any changes to the info.plist I suggest you can revert to the last saved version to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone. I am getting the same error after turning off the dialog that warns you about already running instances when you click "run".

Basically, If I don't shut down previously running instances now by hitting "Stop", I get this error when trying to run.

Took me a while to figure out, but saved me from having to reinstall XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Most often when I come across this issue there is an invalid file reference in my project. Typically references to file(s) in another Xcode project. If you go to the project browser, check for files that (in my case) show just a file icon, no file name. Delete those references, quit Xcode and restart it. Not sure what happens to cause this but this usually does the trick for me. Also, trying to edit the project.pbxproj file in the xcodeproj package contents causes more harm than good. Should be able to fix things to though.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me the other day when I moved the ipa I created for Testflight (beta testing). After I copied it back, it no longer gave me the error. So apparently moving any files in the project folder can cause this error.